# Image format testing in php for uploaded images?

Tags: php, image, validation

With PHP, how can I test that an uploaded file is a valid gif, jpg, or png image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [exif_imagetype](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

Comment: From the manual: "When a correct signature is found, the appropriate constant value will be returned otherwise the return value is FALSE. The return value is the same value that getimagesize() returns in index 2 but exif_imagetype() is much faster." I like this because it's faster, and it doesn't throw an ERROR (like getimagesize() does) when it's not an image, just returns FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

[`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) will parse the file header for "magic bytes" identifying the format. Apart from loading the file into GD and re-saving it, this is the most reliable way of making sure a file is an image.

A number of formats is supported, including BMP, TIFF and PSD.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>If you have GD correctly set up, supporting the right formats,</strike> this should do it.

```
$info = getimagesize("file");
echo $info["mime"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

#### Edit

Never mind, that function has been depreciated. Use [finfo_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php)

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

echo $finfo->file('images/file.png'); // image/png
```