# External image link containing malware

Tags: php, malware

My website allows users to attach external image to their post. Sometimes when the host server of the image has malware.

My website will have this google malware warning
http://media.photobucket.com/image/google%20malware%20warning/unfuccwittable/MalwareWarning.jpg

Is there anything i can do on my end to prevent this? Like a php code to check the image before allowing displaying of the image on my website?

Answer (score 1):

There are [several PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145467/image-format-testing-in-php-for-uploaded-images) that can check a file for whether it is an image.

To make 100% sure, you would have to take every incoming image, create a copy of it using the [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library, and save that copy.

That will make absolutely sure no malware can pass through. 
However, images are likely to lose quality, because GD's JPG compressor is not as good as Photoshop's for example. Also there will be issues with  transparent images (they can be sorted out though).

[CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) images will not work at all with this method, but that's rather good, seeing as Internet Explorer can't display them, anyway.

Comment: the thing is that it is an image, just that the image host server has malware.

Comment: @damian but that has nothing to do with the image uploading process then, does it? How would the malware make it across to your site then if you're just fetching the image?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i just created an account. It's not affecting my server, it's just that warning, people will not proceed on to the website. I tried to google seems to not be able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I gotta say, there is NOTHING like posting a big red warning on your site to attract visitors.

Since your using PHP, all public images should be ran through php-gd. This will verify its an image or fail. Also, it will remove geotagging metadata (stuff that some people consider private)